# ArcReader 10.1 trouble (loading and printing is taking very long ime)

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, database, printing, feature-class, arcreader

We've run into printing problems in ArcReader 10.1. Our trouble is with a particular floodplain feature class located in an SDE database. It simply takes forever to load! Then, when printing, it takes at least 10 minutes. Does anybody else have this issue/know a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If possible, have all of your layers are in the same projection.

In a past project, we found that the reproject on the fly was very costly in ArcReader, and having all layers in the same projection increased performance almost 10x.

Answer (score 0):

If using Windows: ArcGIS supports printing to any Microsoft certified Windows printer using the native driver in ArcGIS. Please note that some printer drivers do not support complex maps, and the ArcPress printer driver or additional hardware may be needed for these complex maps.

Esri recommends the following configuration when printing large maps with the ArcPress printer drivers:

**If large complex maps do not print, then reboot the computer to ensure the pagefile system is cleared**. If the pagefile system is not a dedicated drive or partition, make sure that drive does not need to be defragmented.
    **Disk Space: at least 10 GB of free space is required on the drive where %TEMP% is** located, as potentially large temporary files will be written there while ArcPress is processing a map for printing.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#//015100000067000000

Personally I would recommend 8GB of RAM on Windows to print large files. It is the caching that is slowing the process down.